# Reassigning a value returned from a function in Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, variable-assignment

My title might be a bit off but I didn't really know how to formulate myself.

Say I have a function that takes a data structure and maybe some other arguments and returns a value from that data structure. How do I reassign that return value?

Here's a simple example of what I want to do:

Let's say I have a function foo,

```
def foo(x, n):
    return x[n]
```

and a list l,

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

what I want to do is something like this:

```
foo(l, 1) = 0 #this results in an error
```

Which I want to result in this:

```
l = [1, 0, 3, 4, 5]
```

This example may be trivial with another approach but let's imagine my function for retrieving an item from the list is more complex.

Edit:
Maybe my description was too unclear, basically what I want is an assignment operator that works like setf in lisp.
I want my function to return some sort of pointer to a value in a data structure. I then want to change the value that the pointer is pointing at.
What I want to use it for i basically something like this: (that I don't understand why I didn't just begin with as an example)

```
def foo(l, indexes):
    if indexes == []:
        return l
    else:
        return foo(l[indexes[0]], indexes[1:])
l = [[1, 2], 3]
foo(l, [0, 1]) = 0 #Again this is what is not working and I understand why it's not working, I just want something that would do what you think this might do.
```

Which I want to result in:

```
l = [[1, 0], 3]
```

Comment: When the function returns the value 2, the value is no longer `l[1]`, but is just a number 2. It is not a valid variable to assign to. What you need to do is pass the number `0` into the function, and assign it to `l[1]` inside the function.

Comment: @ndpu, no, that's not exactly what OP is asking for. `foo` returns a value, you can't use it as an index.

Comment: Since `foo` returns an `int` (in this case), you **CANNOT** assign any other `int` (0) to it!

Comment: Python does not have that kind of "pointer". You realize the problem already from the phrasing of the question: the function returns **a value**, which doesn't have any of the data structure's context. "I want my function to return some sort of pointer to a value in a data structure" If that data structure is a simple `list`, then the "pointer" you want is... an integer which is an index into that list. But usually it would be better to let the function do the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you intend?

```
def foo(thelist, n):
     thelist.append(n)
     return thelist
```

OR are you looking to insert?

```
def foo(thelist, i, n):
     thelist.insert(i , n)
     return thelist
```

@OP after reading you're edited post; check out [link](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748780/is-it-possible-something-like-lvalue-of-perl-or-setf-of-lisp-in-python) there's an example there that may be of use.

According to the stackoverflow post; the answer is no.

Comment: He wants to insert a number into the list at a certain index. `append()` appends the number to the end.

Comment: I was already in the process of editing; thus I posed it with as a question.

Comment: The OP wants to change the list element, not the list itself.

Comment: That link pretty much answers my question, thanks. I didn't find it when I searched for it :(

Answer (score 0):

I still dont understand what you are trying to achieve, so please elaborate on that. Now it looks like what you need is

```
def foo(l, n, number):
    ...logic...
    l[n] = number
    return l
```

Edit: After reading your edit, no. the function returns the *value*, not a *reference* to the item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not possible(The reason is you cannot assign 2 to 0). Instead of using function if you use macro, then you can achieve it. python doesn't have macros as C. But once have a look at [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) to write macros in python.